# Java Simple Linked List

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am taking a course in Data Structures at University and I am having troubles understanding why my Singly Linked List is not following FIFO algorithm.

Here is my Node/PSVM class:

```
public class Node {

    protected int data;
    protected Node next;

    Node(int element){
        this.data = element;
        next = null;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();

        ll.addElement(300);
        ll.addElement(600);
        ll.addElement(900);
        ll.addElement(1200);


        ll.printList();
    }
}
```

This is my Linked List Class:

```
public class LinkedList {

    // create a reference of type node to point to head
    Node head;

    // keep track of the size of ll
    int size = 0;

    void printList() {
        Node n = head;

        for (int i = 0; i < llSize(); i++) {
            System.out.print(n.data + " ");
            n = n.next;

        }
        System.out.println("");
    }


    int llSize() {
        return this.size;
    }

    boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    void addElement(int element) {

        if (isEmpty()) {
            head = new Node(element);

        } else {
            Node nNode = new Node(element);
            Node current = head;

            while(current.next != null){
                current = current.next;
            }

            current.next = nNode;

        }

        this.size++;

    }


}
```

Sorry in advance if this is a basic question/problem. I have asked my professor and she sent me a YouTube link which really didn't help.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: No need to apologize. But you did post the same code twice. You may want to show expected/actual inputs and outputs though

Comment: Oops, sorry. I just edited it and added my LL class.

Comment: I don't see a bug in the code. What's the output you're getting from your `printList` call and what are you expecting? Side note: it's a little odd to put your `main` inside the `Node` class - not a bug, just unexpected.

Comment: I also don't see any logic errors in what you've posted.  One suggestion though, it'd be more efficient to keep a separate reference to the tail node, rather than traversing the entire list every time you add an element.

Comment: Thanks for all the resposes

This is my output:


1200 900 600 300
 
Shouldn't it be outputting in the same order it was inserted? FIFO?
Also, I could put my main in a different file to keep it separate.

Comment: When I run your code I get `300 600 900 1200`.  See https://ideone.com/JwS0I9

Comment: Thank you for all of your responses. I added that while loop after I compiled my code. I guess my next question is the while loop similar to an variable to keep track of the index in the linked list so to speak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has no bugs.

**For the list to behave as FIFO, nodes will be added to one end and deleted from the opposite end.**

Therefore, you will have to implement a **delete** operation. You can maintain separate reference to the head and tail node.